# hundreds of addresses show street view in google.com/maps, but not via the api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-street-view

Google maps has a panoramic view for this address:
550 Peachtree St Ne Atlanta, GA 30308
Gmaps fails to pull up a panoramic view, even though it will pull up the regular map view.
Both are given the latLng of 33.7684944,-84.3860605.  The nuance is that google adjusts the latLng when street view is clicked to 33.768478,-84.385286
Can Gmaps provide a street view for 33.7684944,-84.3860605?  I have a ton of these addresses with which I have the same problem.
code:

```
var geo = new google.maps.Geocoder;
geo.geocode({‘address’:“550 Peachtree St Ne Atlanta, GA 30308”},function(results, status){
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
  var myLatLng = results[0].geometry.location;
panorama = GMaps.createPanorama({
  el: ‘#panorama’,
  lat: myLatLng[“k”],
  lng: myLatLng[“D”]
});
```

Comment: Which street view are you referring to for [550 Peachtree St Ne Atlanta GA 30308](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=550+Peachtree+St+Ne+Atlanta,+GA+30308&hl=en&sll=32.881894,-117.130566&sspn=0.087793,0.110378&hnear=550+Peachtree+St+NE,+Atlanta,+Georgia+30308&t=m&z=16), I don't see a "Streetview" for that result.  That said, [I see an API result for that address](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_Streetview_lookAtB.html?snaptoroad=550%20Peachtree%20St%20Ne%20Atlanta,%20GA%2030308tle%20Rock,%20CO%2080109,%20USA)

Comment: On google maps when you hover over the address input box, a drop down appears with the street-view option.
And I also see the api result for the regular map, geocoded as 33.7684944,-84.3860605. Just not when I try to get the street view with GMaps.createPanorama( (see above code)

Comment: same problem when I tried using the code posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111626/why-are-some-street-view-images-from-the-wrong-angle/28265164#28265164

Comment: The question kinda boils down to whether or not anyone show me how to code to get a streetview for 33.7684944,-84.3860605?  Google maps shows a street view for it, seems that Google's street view adjusts to get the nearest street view - not the exact same co-ordinates.  Can't the gmap api? maybe some version of createPanorama() where it gets the nearest streetview?

Answer (score 0):

Well, there might not be a SV for your exact location so Gmaps will adjust the coordinates to the closest available SV. However, below is the snippet of sample code to [access the SV data](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#StreetViewService) and get the exact pano for your location.(Maybe you will find panoID(s) for some of the other addresses you are having problems with)

Also, if you still want pano for the exact coords/address, you can always provide one(or more) as [custom SV panoramas](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview#CustomStreetView).

Hope this helped.

```js
/*
 * Click the map to set a new location for the Street View camera.
 */

var map;
var berkeley = new google.maps.LatLng(37.869085, -122.254775);
var sv = new google.maps.StreetViewService();

var panorama;

function initialize() {

  panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(document.getElementById('pano'));

  // Set up the map
  var mapOptions = {
    center: berkeley,
    zoom: 16,
    streetViewControl: false
  };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);

  // Set the initial Street View camera to the center of the map
  sv.getPanoramaByLocation(berkeley, 50, processSVData);

  // Look for a nearby Street View panorama when the map is clicked.
  // getPanoramaByLocation will return the nearest pano when the
  // given radius is 50 meters or less.
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      sv.getPanoramaByLocation(event.latLng, 50, processSVData);
  });
}

function processSVData(data, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.StreetViewStatus.OK) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: data.location.latLng,
      map: map,
      title: data.location.description
    });

    panorama.setPano(data.location.pano);
    panorama.setPov({
      heading: 270,
      pitch: 0
    });
    panorama.setVisible(true);

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

      var markerPanoID = data.location.pano;
      // Set the Pano to use the passed panoID
      panorama.setPano(markerPanoID);
      panorama.setPov({
        heading: 270,
        pitch: 0
      });
      panorama.setVisible(true);
    });
  } else {
    alert('Street View data not found for this location.');
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Surprisingly, the the code was not any better at finding the nearest streetview, even when I increased the radius.  For these same addresses, always 'street view data not found'.  I guess that the google maps site adjusts the latLng, but it does not seem to do the same for the api.

Answer (score 0):

Here's something else you can try.

1. Load up the address on maps.google.com
2. Search / browse to the panorama you want to embed in the API
3. Click the little cog icon, and choose 'Share or embed image'
4. In the link displayed, you want to look for a string that looks like a panorama ID (e.g. the bit in bold in this URL: https://www.google.com/maps/place/550+Peachtree+St+NE,+Atlanta,+GA+30308/@33.7684,-84.385294,3a,75y,277.72h,96.38t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1s**6QxXDJ31203GbQIqjZgNfQ**!2e0!4m2!3m1!1s0x88f504707616f8b1:0x48bc02b5988e5608!6m1!1e1?hl=en
5. You can then use that Pano ID directly in your [Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/streetview) code

PS: Please keep in mind that this might not be such a stable technique. Its merely a work around.