# Maps API - Marker on the street

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

In Maps API, is there a way to snap markers to the street? Normally, if you want to set a marker by address (not latlng), the marker is set somewhere inside the building. In my case, this is an issue if you have e.g. a large mall with several shops. I'd prefer to set a marker on the street.

I'm using Maps API v3.

Many thanks!

Comment: related question: [Google Street View JS gives me a view of the side of the house instead of the front](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380616/google-street-view-js-gives-me-a-view-of-the-side-of-the-house-instead-of-the-fr)

Comment: duplicate of: [Google maps api - snap marker to nearest road](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696502/google-maps-api-snap-marker-to-nearest-road)

Comment: thanks geocodezip - the second link did it! didn't find that one by myself - my bad.

Answer (score 0):

Use the directions service.  Request directions to/from the same location, should be on the road closest to the location.

See [related question: Google maps api - snap marker to nearest road](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696502/google-maps-api-snap-marker-to-nearest-road)