# Why doesn't this lat/lon coordinate find nearest road in Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-api

**Problem**

I'm using the Google Maps API Nearest Road to find the nearest road given a lat/lon coordinate.
I've run into a lat/lon coordinate that does not return anything and I have no idea why. The location of this lat/lon coordinate is right next to a road in North Carolina.

[https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=35.77747,-82.4603&key=`{GOOGLE_API_KEY}`](https://roads.googleapis.com/v1/nearestRoads?points=35.77747,-82.4603&key=%60%7BGOOGLE_API_KEY%7D%60)

Why does this return `{}`?

**Google Map Location**

[image]

Comment: Who knows. Data issues can't be dealt with by the SO community.

Comment: @MrUpsidown this question can also be fielded by Google Support. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/support#contact-maps-support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is your point is too far from the road.

You might want to use the [DirectionsService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions) (Web Service), setting the `origin` and `destination` to your input point.

That seems to have a larger tolerance (although still limited) to finding the nearest road.

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=35.77747,-82.4603&destination=35.77747,-82.4603&key=`{GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
```

returns:

```
// snip
   "end_location" : {
      "lat" : 35.777998,
      "lng" : -82.4598565
   },
// snip
   "start_location" : {
      "lat" : 35.777998,
      "lng" : -82.4598565
   },
// snip
```

Related questions:

- [Maps API - Marker on the street](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35989949/maps-api-marker-on-the-street)
- [Google Street View JS gives me a view of the side of the house instead of the front](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30380616/google-street-view-js-gives-me-a-view-of-the-side-of-the-house-instead-of-the-fr)
- [Google maps api - snap marker to nearest road](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16696502/google-maps-api-snap-marker-to-nearest-road)

[proof of concept fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/g9joe7wn/)

[image: screenshot of original marker and closest point on road]

**code snippet:**

```js
const point = {
  lat: 35.77747,
  lng: -82.4603
}

function initMap() {
  const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  const directionsRenderer = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer({
    preserveViewport: true
  });
  const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
    zoom: 18,
    center: point,
  });
  const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: point,
    title: "input point"
  })
  directionsRenderer.setMap(map);

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer);
}

function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsRenderer) {
  directionsService.route({
      origin: point,
      destination: point,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
    },
    (response, status) => {
      if (status === "OK") {
        directionsRenderer.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert("Directions request failed due to " + status);
      }
    }
  );
}
```

```css
/* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */

#map {
  height: 100%;
}


/* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Directions Service</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <!-- jsFiddle will insert css and js -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Async script executes immediately and must be after any DOM elements used in callback. -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" async></script>
</body>

</html>
```